# Sorting algorithm for set of elements, when I have comparison of just some pairs not all of them

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, sorting

Is there some kind of algorithm for sorting of set, when there is comparison of just some pairs?

Example 1: 
set(a, b, c, d, e)
pairs(a>b, ce)

Example 2: 
set(a, b, c, d, e)
pairs(a>b, d>b, c>d, d>e)

Comment: I don't understand what "pairs(a>b, ce)" is supposed to mean.  But perhaps look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was considered by Kahn and Saks in their paper [Balancing poset extensions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00565647). Earlier related works are Fredman, [How good is the information theory bound in sorting?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397576900785) and Linial, [The information-theoretic bound is good for merging](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/304c/16423212c7028066772104589eadd99914ff.pdf).

Kahn and Saks showed that partially sorted lists can be sorted in $O(\log M)$, where $M$ is the number of possible orderings consistent with the partial order. I'm not sure that their algorithm is efficient, though. The best constant in the big O is the subject of the [1/3–2/3 conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/3%E2%80%932/3_conjecture).